# How to clear o deactivate autosaved data in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, file

Recently, files take 2 seconds to show up when I load them as recent files.
I realized that it only happen with a file: index.html, below it says the following:

```
 index.html has auto save data; consider M-x recover-this-file
```

SO, I assume that Emacs is loading the autosaved files that's why it load slow

I added `(setq auto-save-default nil)` to my .emacs and I deleted my .recent folders but
it still saying that there's saved data in index.html.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your settings, the auto saved file likely exists in the same directory as the file (index.html in this case).  Something like #index.html#, I think.

EDIT: note that auto-save-default affects whether emacs writes auto-save files, not whether it uses any existing ones.